# remove label and button when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made two labels(Label1 and Label 2 and two remove button for each labels) by using html, javascript and jquery for my learning purposes.

Now I want the label and button to be removed when the cross button is clicked.

I tried

```
$(".labels").closest().remove();
```

But it does not work. Please help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Page 2</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-md-2 labels">
    <label>Label 1 </label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs removeBtn">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document)
    .ready(
      function() {
       var formGroupRowDiv = $(
         document.createElement('div')).attr(
         "class", 'form-group row');
       var labelTwoDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("class", 'col-md-2 labels');

       var removeBtnDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("class", 'col-md-1 removeBtn');

       labelTwoDiv.appendTo(formGroupRowDiv).html(
         '<label>Label 2</label>');

       removeBtnDiv
         .appendTo(formGroupRowDiv)
         .html('<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs removeDate">'
             + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'
             + '</button>');

       $(formGroupRowDiv).appendTo('.container');

       $(".removeBtn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".labels").closest().remove();

       });
      });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").click(".removeBtn", function(e) {
   $(e.target).parent().parent().siblings().find("label").remove()
});
```

Since you are dynamically generating the divs, you cant just bind the handler to the divs that appear on load. You need to bind it to something higher up (like body)

- `e.target` here is the removeBtn
- `.parent()` will return a jQuery object of the parent
- `.siblings()` will return all of it [the parent's] siblings
- `.find()` will filter to the passed selector
- `.remove()` will remove it from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Basically you had 4 problems here:

1. You don't want to remove all the `closest()` elements of any `.labels` element that exists on the page (you want to remove a specific `.labels` element that is the closest to the current `.removeBtn` you just clicked.
2. The `closest` is not what you are looking for, but actually the `prev` element.
3. Since your structure for your HTML is different between the two `.removeBtn` elements you have - you will need two different selectors.

The first selector will be `$(this).prev('.labels')` and the second will be `$(this).parent().prev('.labels')`.

4. If you also want to remove the button that was just clicked - use `$(this).remove();`.

This is the fist to your code:

```
$(".removeBtn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).prev('.labels').length) {
    $(this).prev('.labels').remove();
  } else if ($(this).parent().prev('.labels').length) {
    $(this).parent().prev('.labels').remove();
  }
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$(document)
.ready(
  function() {
    var formGroupRowDiv = $(
      document.createElement('div')).attr(
      "class", 'form-group row');
    var labelTwoDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("class", 'col-md-2 labels');

    var removeBtnDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("class", 'col-md-1 removeBtn');

    labelTwoDiv.appendTo(formGroupRowDiv).html(
      '<label>Label 2</label>');

    removeBtnDiv
    .appendTo(formGroupRowDiv)
    .html('<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs removeDate">'
          + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'
          + '</button>');

    $(formGroupRowDiv).appendTo('.container');

    $(".removeBtn").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($(this).prev('.labels').length) {
        $(this).prev('.labels').remove();
      } else if ($(this).parent().prev('.labels').length) {
        $(this).parent().prev('.labels').remove();
      }
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Page 2</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-md-2 labels">
    <label>Label 1 </label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs removeBtn">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to remove the cross button as well byadding            $(this).prev('.removeBtn').remove() to the if condition and 
$(this).parent().prev('.removeBtn').remove() to else if condition but it's not removing.

Comment: In your question you said you want to remove the `.labels` element, and now in the comment you are talking about the `.removeBtn` element. You should decide which of them you want.

Comment: sorry. it should be both labels and buttons. I will edit my question.